# Amazon AWS load balancer sending me to wrong instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I'm very new to AWS, and am trying to forward internet-facing traffic to two EC2 instances that are up and running with a load balancer.

I already have one LB running (let's call it the "first" LB) with ports 443 and 80 open. This one is working just fine, I believe. In Route 53 I have a record that points to this first LB's DNS:

`www.mysite.com    A    production-176xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com.`

My second LB seems to be sending me to the instances behind the first LB. I know this because when I type in the FQDN for the second load balancer

`stress-test-production-836xxxxxxxx.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com`

my browser ends up loading a page over https, even though I've only configured this second LB to work over HTTP.

Any thoughts on what might be going on here?

Comment: You've configured it incorrectly, obviously. The trick is working out which bit you've misconfigured, which you really need console access to do.

Comment: Do instances behind the _second_ ELB have an automatic redirect to HTTPS (and to the "www.mysite.com" DNS name) for any non-HTTPS requests?